op_kwargs Not Populating with Parameters in Jinja Template for Airflow DAG Generator
I am building an automatic DAG generator from a configuration YAML. My problem is that when generating the DAG, the value that should appear in 'op_kwargs' does not show up. The other values are configured correctly, but this one does not. I am sharing the part of the Jinja template where I handle this, as well as the Python file where I manage the parameters and the YAML configuration.
JINJA TEMPLATE:
with DAG(
    dag_id="{{ dag_id }}",
    default_args={{ default_args | tojson }},
    schedule_interval="{{ schedule_interval }}",
    catchup={{ catchup }}
) as dag:
    
    # Definir las tareas
    {% for task_id, task_info in tasks.items() %}
        {% set params = task_info['params'] if task_info['params'] is defined else {} %}
        {% if task_info['type'] == "python_callable" %}
        {{ task_id }} = PythonOperator(
            task_id="{{ task_id }}",
            python_callable={{ task_info['command'] }},
            op_kwargs={{ params | tojson}},
            dag=dag
        )

PYTHON FILE:
def _create_python_callable_task(self, task_id, task_info):
        """
        Crear una tarea que ejecuta una función Python.
        """
        # Obtener el nombre de la función a ejecutar (de acuerdo al comando en el YAML)
        command = task_info.get("command")
        command = FUNCTIONS_MAP.get(command)
        args = task_info.get("params", {})  # Asegúrate de que "params" esté correctamente asignado
        print(f"Creating task {task_id} with params: {args}")  # Línea de depuración
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            python_callable=command,
            op_kwargs=args, 
            dag=self.dag
        )
        self.task_list[task_id] = {'task': task, 'type': 'python_callable', 'info': task_info}

CONFIGURATION YAML
my_workflow: 
  airflow_config:
    dag_id: "ruedas"
    default_args:
      owner: "Marcos"
      retries: 3
      start_date: "2024-10-18"
    schedule_interval: "@daily"
    catchup: False
  tasks:
      extract_data:
        type: "python_operator"
        command: "data_extract_and_load"
        dependencies: []  # Depende de la tarea definida ahi
        params:  # Definir un diccionario de parámetros
          config_path: "/opt/airflow/dags/scripts/config/config.yml"

      extract_data2:
        type: "python_operator"
        command: "data_extract_and_load"
        dependencies: [extract_data]  # Depende de la tarea definida ahi
        params:  # Definir un diccionario de parámetros
          config_path: "/opt/airflow/dags/scripts/config/config.yml"

FINAL DAG:
with DAG(
    dag_id="ruedas",
    default_args={"owner": "Marcos", "retries": 3, "start_date": "2024-10-18 00:00:00"},
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False
) as dag:

        extract_data = PythonOperator(
            task_id="extract_data",
            python_callable=data_extract_and_load,
            op_kwargs={},
            dag=dag
        )
        
        extract_data2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id="extract_data2",
            python_callable=data_extract_and_load,
            op_kwargs={},
            dag=dag
        )

muchas gracias de antemano.
I tried a lot of things, such as changing the template, the python file etc but nothing works.

Have you considered using dagfactory?
